# How to calculate the perpendicular vector of a given vector $A=[a,b,c]$ in cartesian syatem? Any other information is not there

Tags: vectors, geometry

How to calculate the perpendicular vector of a given vector $A=[a,b,c]$ in Cartesian system? Any other information is not there.

Comment: Why not use the definition of dot product or cross product as a starting point?

Comment: There are infinitely many.

Answer (score 1):

It is most convenient to calculate the unit vector perpendicular to the given vector $\textbf A=[a,b,c]$ . Let this vector be $\hat{\textbf n}=[n_1,n_2,n_3]$ .
Then, by the property of unit vector,$$n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2=1\tag{1}$$ As $\hat{\textbf n}$ is perpendicular to $\textbf A$ , the dot product of them is $0$ , i.e., $\textbf A \cdot \hat{\textbf n}=0$ which implies,$$an_1+bn_2+cn_3=0\tag{2}$$ 
Again, as $\hat{\textbf n}$ is perpendicular to $\textbf A$ and $\hat{\textbf n}$ is a unit vector(of magnitude 1), the magnitude of their cross product is equal to the magnitude of $\textbf A$ itself :$$|\textbf A \times \hat{\textbf n}|=|\textbf A|\,|\hat{\textbf n}|\,\displaystyle{\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}}=A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\tag{3}$$
Now, $$\textbf A \times \hat{\textbf n}=\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{\textbf i}& \hat{\textbf j}& \hat{\textbf k}\\
a & b & c\\
n_1 & n_2 & n_3
\end{vmatrix}=(bn_3-cn_2)\hat{\textbf i}+(cn_1-an_3)\hat{\textbf j}+(an_2-bn_1)\hat{\textbf k}\tag{4}$$
So, from equations (3) and (4), we get, $$\sqrt{{(bn_3-cn_2)}^2+{(cn_1-an_3)}^2+{(an_2-bn_1)}^2}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\tag{5}$$
So, there are three equations (1), (2) and (5) for the three unknowns $n_1$ , $n_2$ and $n_3$ . Solving them, we get the desired vector $\hat{\textbf n}$

Alternatively, one might get the answer without assuming the vector is a unit vector. Then, equation (1) is not needed. After writing equations (2) and (5), you may choose any particular value for any one of $n_1$ , $n_2$ , $n_3$ and find out the values of the remaining variables from (2) and (5).
Again, you can also choose particular values for any two of the coordinates of the unknown vector and solve for the value of the third one from equation (2).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: *the unit vector is a unique one.* No, it isn’t. There are an infinite number of unit vector perpendicular to any vector.

Comment: Yes I see you are right @G. Smith ! But then the solution I suggested should not give a unique vector. Can you say how is this evident from the three equations (1), (2) and (5) ?

Comment: @G. Smith do you mean to say that every vector in 3D has a unit vector perpendicular to it which is either $\hat n$ or $-\hat n$? But then the solution I suggested should not give a unique vector but two possible solutions for the two possible directions. Can you say how is this evident from the three equations (1), (2) and (5) ?

Comment: No, I didn’t say there are two. I said there are an *infinite* number. This should be obvious. Take a simple case where the original vector points in the $+z$ direction. Then every unit vector in the $xy$ plane is perpendicular, and there are an infinite number of these; they lie on a circle and can be written as $\cos\theta\hat x+\sin\theta\hat y$. I am not going to figure out what’s wrong with your argument, but I hope that I have convinced you that it’s wrong.

Comment: Ok. Anyway, I am thinking whether there are any issues regarding the solvability of the three simultaneous equations. Someone might come with an insight to look into this. Maybe, somehow, it can be shown that they have an infinite number of solutions though I do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is to construct two "arbitrary" vectors, which are perpendicular to $\vec v_0 =(a,b,c)$. Any linear combination of these two vectors is again perpendicular.

The necessary condition for a vector $\vec v_i$ to be perpendicular to $\vec v_0$ is that their scalar product is zero. Thus, we can easily check that 
$$\vec v_1 = \left(\frac{1}{a}, -\frac{1}{b}, 0 \right)$$ 
and 
$$\vec v_2 = \left(\frac{1}{a}, 0, -\frac{1}{c} \right)$$ 
 are perpendicular to $\vec v_0$.

This construction obviously fails if one of the components $\{a, b, c\}$ is zero. Suppose $c=0$, then the vector $\vec v_0$ lies in the $(x,y)$-plane. Thus, any vector which points in $z$-direction is perpendicular to $\vec v_0$. Therefore, we can "renormalise" the vector 
$$\vec v_2 = \left(\frac{1}{a}, 0, -\frac{1}{c} \right)
\to 
(0, 0, -1) = - \vec e_z$$ 
(the procedure is of course mathematically incorrect, but I hope this description helps you to understand the process).

If two components vanish simultaneously, we use the same method. Suppose, $b=0$ and $c=0$. Now the vector $\vec v_2$ points in the  $x$-direction. Hence, the unit vector along the $y$-direction, $\vec e_y = (0,1,0)$, and the unit vector along the $z$-direction, $\vec e_z = (0,0,1)$, are perpendicular to $\vec v_0$.